# Can I input a pandas dataframe into "TfidfVectorizer"? If so, how do I find out how many documents are in my dataframe?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, topic-modeling, tfidfvectorizer

Here's the raw data:

[image: raw data]

Here's about the first half of the data after reading it into a pandas dataframe:
[image: pandas dataframe]

I'm trying to run `TfidfVectorizer` but I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: After pruning, no terms remain. Try a lower min_df or a higher max_df.
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828369/max-df-corresponds-to-documents-than-min-df-error-in-ridge-classifier) post that said the error occurs when the `max_df` value is less than the `min_df` value in `TfidfVectorizer`. I have tried several variations where my `max_df` value is greater than my `min_df` value and still get the same error. So, I think the error might be related to how my data is stored in the pandas dataframe. Am I on the right track? If so, how do I find out how many documents I have in my dataframe? If not, how can I troubleshoot this?

Here's my code:

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5, min_df=0, stop_words=None)
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df)
```

Also, here is the example I am working off of:

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2,
                                   max_features=n_features,
                                   stop_words='english')
```

In the above example, the `min_df` is greater than the `max_df`. I tried doing that exactly but got the following error:

```
ValueError: max_df corresponds to < documents than min_df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a column of data to the `fit_transform` function. Here is the example

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
words = ['trust inten other','feel comfort express view']
df = pd.DataFrame(words,columns = ['words'])
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5, min_df=0, stop_words=None)
# right
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['words'])
# wrong
# tf_idf = tf_idf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df)
```

When you pass `df` to the `fit_transform` function, it will take `['words']` as input, instad of `['trust inten other','feel comfort express view']` as is showed in the example.